# Java synchronized метод с созданием треда

Tags: java, многопоточность

Ну есть например такой код:

```
 private synchronized void create() {
     Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // long operation
        }
    };
    ThreadPool.getThreadPool().exec(r);
}
```

exec(r) создает тред. Что произойдет при двойном вызове create()? Будет ли 2ой вызов ждать завершения первого? И будет ли ждать завершения первого потока? Или для этого обязательно вводить монитор?

Comment: А вы проэкспериментируйте сами и нам расскажите.

Comment: Ok. Я поэкспериментирую когда тестовая среда появиться.

Comment: Кстати, если вы надеетесь, что создаете и запускаете в этом коде отдельный поток, я вас разочарую. Вызывая `run` в явном виде вы просто выполните этот метод в текущем потоке.

Comment: Ок, я это понял, неудачный был пример, я поправил.

Comment: Зачем ждать? Создайте ее сами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, что такое ThreadPool и того, как реализован метод exec. Если он запускает задачу на пуле как ExecutorService, то вероятно exec вернёт управление раньше, чем задача будет выполнено. Так что никто никого ожидать не будет. Второй вызов, конечно будет ждать завершения первого вызова, но не потока.

А всё потому, что надо сначала почитать про synchronized. Пока вы просто гадаете о том, что он делает.

Comment: Да, именно так. Проверил, убедился в этом.

Answer (score 0):

> Или для этого обязательно вводить
>   монитор?

Модификатор `synchronized` и создает монитор.

Только следует помнить, что синхронизация имеет место только при обращении разных тредов к синхронизированному методу одного и тоже объекта, т.е. одного и того же экземпляра. В Вашем случае создается, по-видимому, несколько экземпляров.